# Highlight cells in excel based on whether text exceeds the cell boundary?

Tags: microsoft-excel, adobe-acrobat, text-formatting, mail-merge

I am taking text from excel and pasting it into a fillable PDF using AutoMailMerge. In some cases I have more text than will fit into the PDF field. I've adjusted my excel cell sizes, font, and text size so that they perfectly match my PDF fields so I can see (visually) when they exceed the boundary of the boxes.

I'm wondering if there's a way to highlight cells where the text exceeds the cell boundary though as this would help expedite the process. Maybe some sort of conditional formatting I can apply?

I can't just use a len() function since a box with more line returns or wider characters will take up more space than a box with fewer line returns and thinner characters.

Comment: Hmm. You could paste it all in with the fixed width columns, then select all and enable Text Wrapping... of course `CELL` will natively get you the width but not height of a cell, but this tutorial claims to be able to get you the height of a row as a value in a cell: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1965-excel-display-row-height-column-width.html
So, if you set the row height, then paste your data, then enable text wrap, then measure row height, you can add a conditional formatting (or filter, or whatever) against that measure of row height. That's what I thought of!